R - error with terra::extract : unable to find inherited method for function "extract" for signature "SpatRaster", "SpatialPolygons"
I'm trying to convert an R script using package raster in order to use package terra instead. So I changed the raster::raster function for terra::rast function, and also the raster::extract for terra::extract function.
Reproducible example :
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-180,-20))
cds2 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(100,60), c(120,0), c(120,-55), c(80,0))

polys <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cds1)), 1)))
exo <- rast(cds2) #normally a .tiff file here.

val <- terra::extract(exo, polys)

I get the following error :
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :  unable to find inherited method for the function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"SpatRaster", "SpatialPolygons"’
How can I fix the error and extract the values from exo without using raster package in the script ?
Thanks for your answers.

The error message is:
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :  
unable to find inherited method for the function ‘extract’
 for signature ‘"SpatRaster", "SpatialPolygons"’

And if you look at ?terra::extract you can see that there is a method for
"SpatRaster", "SpatVector"

So you need to represent your polygons as a SpatVector. You can do:
val <- terra::extract(exo, vect(polys))

And in real life you could probably do something like this
polys <- vect("filename.shp")
val <- terra::extract(exo, polys)

The bottom line is that if you want to use "terra" instead of the obsolete "raster" package, you should not be using the "sp" package to represent vector data.

Thank you so much for this very clear answer. I understand why the message error appeared now and how to resolve it.

I'm guessing you're not expecting your exo to look like

To make your polygon(s)
vect(cds1, type = 'polygons', crs = 'EPSG:4326')
 class       : SpatVector 
 geometry    : polygons 
 dimensions  : 1, 0  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : -180, -60, -60, 5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
polys <- vect(cds1, type = 'polygons', crs = 'EPSG:4326')

And consider the matrix cds2 as source for spatial extent
exo_pre <- rast(ext(c(min(cds2[, 1]), max(cds2[, 1]), min(cds2[ ,2]), max(cds2[, 2]))), crs = 'EPSG:4326', resolution = 1)
exo_pre
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 115, 40, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 80, 120, -55, 60  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)

exo_pre currently has no values. What are they and where should they be? If we plot cds2 as a polygon, we see where they should be, a trapezoid area inside rast. Giving values, then masking with the cds2 polygon
values(exo_pre) <- 1:ncell(exo_pre)
cds2_poly <- vect(cds2, type = 'polygons', crs = 'EPSG:4326')
exo <- mask(exo_pre, cds2_poly)
plot(exo)


While the problem of polygons is solved, extract will not work between exo derived from cds2 and polys derived from cds1 because they don't overlap.

Supposing
cds2_2 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(-100,-60), c(120,0), c(120,-55), c(80,0))
# or
cds2_3 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(-100,-60), c(-120,0), c(120,-55), c(80,0))

there is overlap and extract, extracts
extract(exo_2, polys)
    ID lyr.1
1    1     1
2    1     2
3    1     3
4    1     4
5    1     5
#<---snip--->


Thank you for your response. Maybe my reproducible example wasn't appropriate. cds1 is, in my real data, a shapefile. the shapefile (cds1) and the tiff file (cds2) intersect, because there are data in the tiff file that I am able to extract using the raster package. I'm getting an error only when I use rast and terra::extract instead of raster and raster::extract.

Perhaps there are some - signs in  cds2 that would lead to intersect, but I'm somewhat constrained by data provided. And welcome to Stackoverflow. Perhaps link to the .tif...
